# Send Query result into a Text file in SqlServer

Tags: sql-server

I want to send the result from a scalar variable into a text file,

My Code looks like this

```
 DECLARE @test varchar(10)

 SET @test='This is sample text'

 EXEC master..xp_cmdshell'bcp ' + @test + ' queryout "D:\sample.txt" -S LocalHost -U 
 sa -P 123 -c  -T -t'
```

But this is showing the following errors

```
 output
 usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
 [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
 [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
 [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
 [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
 [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
 [-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]
 [-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
 [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
 [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
 [-h "load hints"]         [-x generate xml format file]
 NULL
```

Dont know how to give the format assigning a scalar variable value in bcp command
   Please any one help.

And tried in this way also

```
  Create table #sample
  (
   productid int
  )

  Insert into #sample(productid) values(1001098)

  EXEC master..xp_cmdshell'bcp "select * from #sample" queryout "D:\sample.txt" -S 
  LocalHost -U sa -P 123 -c  -T -t'
```

It gives as Error that

```
   #sample does not exist (in bcp command line)
```

Can any one please solve this.
     Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put all of the sql into the string passed to bcp; #sample is not available to it if defined elsewhere

Comment: Could u please give me  the syntax for passing a string into bcp command. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, a temp table is bound to a scope, and thus cannot be used in a different process ID.

But, you can declare a global temp table (be sure to delete it afterward and make sure to use a very specific name to make sure you don't interfere with some other code).

To do so, you just have to double the '#' in the table name.

```
if object_ID('tempdb..##sample') is not null
    drop table ##sample

Create table ##sample
(
 productid int
)

Insert into ##sample(productid) values(1001098)
```

Then all you have to do is your output.

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell'bcp "select * from ##sample" queryout "d:\sample.txt" -w -U sa -P 123 -S server_name\instance_name'
```

As you can see I changed a couple of switches too.
I found it's preferable to use -w to generate ansi characters, so I removed -c.
-T is for trusted connection, but since you provide a username and password, you don't need it.

Then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT *FROM [YOURDATABASE].[dbo].[YOURTABLE]"  queryout "f:\newOUTPUT.txt" -S DESKTOP-A5CFJSH\MSSQLSERVER1 -UYOURUSERNAME -PYOURPASSWORD -n '
```