# How to use SQL outfile command correctly?

Tags: database, t-sql, powershell, sql-server-2012, file-io

I couldn't find an answer so far. What I want to do is to outfile my sql table into a .txt file or csv. (txt if possible)

What i try is :

```
SELECT * FROM [mydb] INTO OUTFILE 'd:\scripts\powershell\123.txt';
```

the return is :

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.
```

I also tried to select just some of the columns. Also tried to create the text file first...

I use SQL-Server-2012

Comment: For which DBMS is that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932718/send-query-result-into-a-text-file-in-sqlserver Refer this

Comment: There is no such command in SQL Server.  Tools that can do it include BCP, SSIS and SQLCMD.

Comment: use sql server Import/Export wizard

Answer (score 2):

goto your Database right click

```
DataBase --> Right Click --> Tasks --> ExportData
```

Sql Server `Import/Export Wizard` will open. Provide all the information like DataSource , ServerName and Databases Name, Table Name, Click Next and then provide all the information about the destination .

Comment: Not aware of any t-sql that can Export data to an external file.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be the SSIS Import/Export Wizard with a query source and the quickest and easiest way to do that is described in Muhammed Ali's answer.

But if that is not an option, in theory you could achieve this by combining xp_cmdshell with SQLCMD, although I haven't tried it myself.

You can find information on xp_cmdshell [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx), there is an excellent article by Pinal Dave that describe what you are attempting using SQLCMD from the admin command prompt you can read it [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/05/sql-server-exporting-query-results-to-csv-using-sqlcmd/).

You may end up with something along the lines of this:

> EXEC  master..xp_cmdshell 'SQLCMD -S *YourSQLServer* -d *YourDatabase* -U
>   *YourUserName* -P *YourPassword* -Q “*Your Query*” -s “,” -o
>   “C:*Yourfilename*.csv”', no_output

If I get chance this weekend I'll have a play around and come back and expand this answer, if not good luck, I hope this helps.